# What's up with the tags that look different?

Tags: support, tags, meta, moderator-tags, required-tags

They look indented or something like that. Are those the "moderator only" tags?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- red tags = moderator only
- border tags = required on every question

Comment: Could you elaborate on "required on every question"? Do you mean that each question should be categorised "discussion", "support" etc? Are there plans to support this with a radio button or something similar? I'm not trying to hassle you on this - I know features take time to implement! I'm just trying to get a better sense of where the system is headed.

Comment: And, is this feature going to be available on SO/SF/SU later?

Comment: The red tags look horrible on a revision log, see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/5656/list

Comment: @hayalci: I know! We need a new web site: **meta.meta.stackoverflow.com** :-)