# Whats different about status-bydesign tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's up with the tags that look different?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6048/whats-up-with-the-tags-that-look-different)

What is the **red** colored `status-bydesign` label?

---

To clarify my question (which Jon has quickly answered),
The **red** color indicated that the tag was different and
I had just started noticing the borders (that Thomas mentions).
I was curious about the color and the meaning of the actual tag.
thanks.. .

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6048/whats-up-with-the-tags-that-look-different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "this isn't a bug, it's how it's meant to work."

For instance, suppose you wrote a post on Meta saying, "I can't delete my own question. Bug!" and it turned out that your question had a bunch of answers with upvotes, then this behaviour is "by design" - it's preventing content which other users have found useful from being deleted.

Comment: I think he's asking why it's red.

Comment: don't think he's referring to the tag itself, just the new 'red' tags. like "status-declined" and so on. My guess is that these are moderator tags to classify questions that are being closed.

Comment: That is nice. Is this behavior expected on SO/SU/SF too?

Answer (score 1):

Oh. I think I figured out my own question, thanks to yours.

The bordered tags are mandatory user tags. The red tags are moderator only tags.

Comment: And as I was typing this, Jeff posted in my question confirming that this is true.