# Is there any messaging system in place?

Tags: feature-request, comments

I've seen some users that sould be comunicated some important information (stop flaming, please, please proofread your questions) and many questions about wether there would be private messaging have been clear that this won't be implemented in the near future for "political", "vision" or mission statement reasons.

But for mods, I gess it would be very usefull to be able to send short messages, viewable with the magic envelope, and a small sumary showing like the "You've got new answers" banners.

Is *this* specific feature not planed?

I'm not proposing *Private Messages*, rather an *Administrative Information* or *Public Service Announcement* for mods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've seen some users that sould be comunicated some important information (stop flaming, please, please proofread your questions)

Add a comment to their latest train wreck.

> But for mods, I gess it would be very usefull to be able to send short messages,

You can `flag` a specific question or answer to bring it to a mod's attention.

Answer (score 3):

Messaging features have been consistently denied based on the fact that Stack Overflow isn't a social media site. It's a place to go for questions and answers, not a place to have conversations. Most non personal communication can be placed inside comments to convey the message, and behavior is easier to enforce when it's all in the public eye.

It has also been pointed out quite often that if users want to be contacted, they can place their info in their profile. For other users it is assumed that they do not wish to be contacted directly.

Answer (score 1):

How about the Contact Us link at the bottom of every page that makes it easy to send email to team@stackoverflow.com.   Presumably this would include moderators.

Comment: Are you saying that it should include moderators? As far as I know mods aren't privileged to those emails.

Comment: Mods do not get any emails. The closest thing we get to contact is if you flag something for moderator attention, and that still requires us to actually log in and look.

Comment: Hmmm.  I guess I was assuming that "team" included mods.  Perhaps there should be a Contact Mods link.

Answer (score 1):

The central idea around the stackoverflow.com knowledge exchanges, is exchanging knowledge publicly. You can see why a private message doesn't fit into this. Additionally the public nature tends to put people on their better if not best behavior.

Comments and moderator flagging allow for feedback. I assume the moderator feedback is considered somewhat private, but that doesn't mean it could be made public for behavioral modification.

Answer (score 0):

You can look on the user's profile page and see if they list contact details.

There are no plans on implementing messaging features any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

It is a **No** with tag [`status-bydesign`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/whats-different-about-status-bydesign-tag-closed).